# What does "Exclusive of Load" mean?

Tags: power-supply, load

**Short Version**:  Does "30mA exclusive of load" mean the minimum draw while idling, or avg. draw?

**Long Version**:  While designing a circuit to interface with a radar sensor similar to [this](http://www.bannerengineering.com/en-US/products/sub/83#specs), I've noticed that the current draw listed specifies "30mA, *exclusive of load*.  At first I would imagine that by this they would mean that the device itself draws 30mA without anything attached to it drawing power, but there isn't any way or need to attach accessories etc. to this device.

Would 30mA be the minimum power draw, average power draw, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the power to operate the device not including the power that is also sent out of the device as an output signal.

On that sensor you linked to it could output as much as 150mA to a load - that is not included in the power consumption specification.